# Finding date range for current week, from every week

Tags: php, date

Suppose I have a date available with me:
2012-06-11

I want to find date range for Current Week,

by today Current Week:  2012-06-06 ~ 2012-06-12 (Wednesday to Next Tuesday)

ex1. 06-17(sun)   range=  06-13(wed) ~ 06-19(tue)
ex2: 06-21(Thu)   range= 06-20(wed) ~ 06-26(tue)

How can I find it?

Comment: Please use the search. I'm pretty sure this has been asked before. And please ask only one question at once. I've removed the second question (that one "How to search for a date in MySQL?" which actually looked pretty good).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-06-21 last wednesday')), ' ~ ', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-06-21 tuesday'));
```

There is probably a better, more efficient, way to do it, but this is the quick and easy way